# Как сделать перезапуск уровня при падении персонажа в пропасть?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Я новичок, изучаю Unity 3D, пишу на C#. Экспериментирую на одной игре. Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой, как сделать перезагрузку уровня (`SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name)`) при падении главного персонажа в пропасть?

Comment: Ну триггер поставь в пропасти, или ниже определенной координаты если опустился

Comment: @Xumera_hZ я не знаю как реализовать, что если он опустился ниже определенных координат, делать перезагрузку лвлва. Можете объяснить подробнее?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ написал в методе Jump:
if (gameObject.transform.position.y < -10)
  {
   Thread.Sleep (500);
   SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name);
  }
не получилось

Comment: А ты сцены в build положил?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ просто надо было в update писать, уже получилось

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто, ставишь пустой объект, бокс коллайдер с галочкой `istrigger` и на него скрипт:

```
Void OnTriggerEnter(){
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно,
     `if(transform.position.y <= 0){/*...*/}`
Вместо `0` можно писать координату по высоте, при опускании ниже которой игрок респавнится.